# Flip an unfair coin. Find: (a) p, exactly 7 heads (b) p, exactly 7 tails (c) p, atleast 7 heads

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Suppose that you flip an unfair coin *ten times*, where $p(heads) = 3/4$  and $p(tails) = 1/4$. Find

a) p(exactly 7 heads)
b) p(exactly 7 tails)
c) p(atleast 7 heads)

Hi, I am really new to probability problems. Kindly guide me on how to solve this kind of problem. Thankyou

Comment: These are straight forward calculations using the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: For  p(7 heads):

n=10, x=7, p=3/4, q=1-p, 
Are these value correct to put in binomial distribution formula?

Comment: @SaraRafiq Yes, for **a)** these are the right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One coin flip can be interpreted as a Bernoulli trial with success probability $p=\frac{3}{4}$ for heads. Ten coin flips will give us a binomial distribution with parameter $n=10$ and $p=\frac{3}{4}$. The probability for exact $r$ heads is
\begin{align}
B(n,p,r)=\binom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}
\end{align}
You have to calculate

- $B(10,0.75,7)$
- $B(10,0.75,3)$
- $B(10,0.75,7)+\ldots +B(10,0.75,10)$